# Where does weight mass conversion ratio '0.00259' come from in Nastran?

Tags: simulation, nastran

I think this is very fundamental question.

I am wondering why 0.00259 is used as weight-mass conversion ratio, when inch/pound unit is used in Nastran.

Could anyone explain the reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the inverse of the [acceleration of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration) g in imperial units. 
$$
1 g = 386.1 in/s^2
$$

$$
1/g = 0.00259 s^2/in
$$

You need that since:

$$
weight = mass * g
$$